# console.log causing an error when console is open

Tags: javascript, onclick, console.log

So I'm noticing some odd behaviour in my javascript and I would like to understand why.
In the code below, I am using the [RecordRTC.js library](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/) which is a WebRTC library to record a video.  Everything runs as expected until I stop recording.  Then the function below runs.

```
function endRcrd(rrtc, video) {
    rrtc.stopRecording(function(videoURL) {
        video.src = videoURL;
        var blob = rrtc.blob;
        var fileType = 'video';
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append(fileType + '-blob', blob);

        s.onclick = function(formData) {
            var pathV;
            xhr('../save.php', formData, function (fileURL) { pathV = fileURL; });    // this line
            s.innerHTML = "Saved";
            console.log("formData: ");   // and this line
        };
    });
}
```

What I am not understanding is that there is 2 lines of code in there that when one or the other is commented out, it runs fine.  But when both are there it fails with this error:

`Media resource blob:https://mywebsite.org/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx could not be decoded.`

The 2 lines are:

```
xhr('../save.php', formData, function (fileURL) { pathV = fileURL; });
```

and:

```
console.log("formData: ");
```

These are both inside my click handler `s.onclick`
I'd imagine this is a compiler error, as this code won't be executed until I click my save button ("s").  But why when just one of the two and not just one or both?

Comment: what is xhr? are you sure window.console && window.console.log are even available??

Comment: Based on the above, it seems like you should focus on what's causing that decoding error. It could be an issue with your blob, FormData object, etc. or a back-end issue (what is the response code/body?), but it's _very_ unlikely that the `console.log` method call has anything to do with it.